# edited an .SWF, locally the changes made are okay, but when on server changes are not fully visible

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, caching, flash

I just edited an .SWF file I have on my website home page for a while now. I update the SWF frequently with new pictures. It's actually a picture slideshow, consisting out of 6 images. I used Adobe Flash CS4 Pro to edit the file, with just swapping all the pictures (JPGS) in it for other ones. I also have some small AS where I just have the URL:

```
on(release) { getURL("link"); }
```

so that's nothing fancy at all. I saved and published everything (CTRL+ENTER) and the .SWF played well, and tested it in IE8 and FF. 
Then I uploaded the SWF to my test server, overwriting the existing SWF file.

Now the problem: all pictures but one show up well. Of the 6 images, the second image is actually the old image that was in its place. I downloaded the .SWF from the testserver and inspected the SWF and guess what: the old picture wasn't in it, instead the correct image was in the SWF. Even after reloading the page hitting CTRL+F5 still the wrong image shows. FF though shows the SWF correctly.
So I then opened the page on another computer using IE8 and there the SWF works well, showing the correct second image.
What's wrong with my first computer's browser? It's also the computer I edited the SWF with. I DO remember like I first saved and uploaded the wrong SWF (with the old 2nd image still in it) to the testserver, and later on uploading the correct one (proper 2nd image)

I think IE8 has cached the wrong SWF, and now memorized it someway not willing to see that the file has actually been changed, but what to do so IE8 starts showing the correct SWF??

Comment: Did you try just clearing IE's cache manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, 
changed the filename and now it works...

Comment: Changing the filename effectively causes the browser to assume it's a new fle, and redownload it. (The old file was being cached). Be sure to accept your own answer (checkmark) if you answered your own question!